# How to asynchronously process the object in queue and do post request in Jersey

Tags: java, asynchronous, jersey

I have some code that

1-convert some data to JSONObject

2-add the JSONObject to a queue

3-peek() JSONObject from the queue and send it to an external API

4-if get 200 remove the JSONObject from the queue. if get 5xx resend this object again.

Following is the code I have done so far.

```
public class QueueProcessor {

private static Queue<JSONObject> objectQueue;

static {
     objectQueue = new ObjectQueue<JSONObject>();
}

public void addToQueue(JSONObject json) {

     objectQueue.add(auditEvent);
     //do some *ASYNCHRONOUSLY* process with the queue items



     sendRequest(persistantQueue.peek()); 
}

 public void sendRequest(JSONObject json) {

  Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
  WebTarget baseTarget = client.target("someUrl");
  Invocation.Builder builder = baseTarget.request();
  Response response = builder.post(Entity.entity(json.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

  int code = response.getStatus();   
  if (200 == code) {
        objectQueue.remove();
     }
  if (500 <= code) {
     //resending the object
  }
}
```

My question is in the addToQueue method what should I need to implement to make this whole process to be asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the QueueProcessor running in one thread just taking things out of the queue and sending requests in new threads.  I would use the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html.  If the request fails in the new threads you would requeue the json object.